# How to use array.push on array with a defined index?

Tags: javascript

How do I use array.push to add an object with a custom index in an array?

I have this script but it doesnt work. Chrome's Javascript console is not outputting errors

```
var tempList = new Array();
$('#add').click(function(){
  var split = $('#itemid').val().split('_');
  var itemid = split['0'];
  var lbs = $('#lbs').val();
  tempList.push(tempList['itemid'] = lbs);
  for (var i; i<=(tempList.length - 1); i++){
    if (i==0){
      var list = tempList[i]+ '<br />';
    } 
    else{
      var list =  list + tempList[i]+ '<br />';
    }
  }
  alert(list);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old answer: Your script may not work, because you have to initialise the index of the loop: `var i=0;`

---

**Question** (new, at the comment chain):

> Hi, hope you dont mind another question but how do I display the
>   content of `tempList[]` in a table?

**Answer**:
See the code below. After the loop, I have included several ways to append the data/table to the body, because you didn't specify which method you wanted.

```
var tempList = {};
$('#add').click(function(){
    var split = $('#itemid').val().split('_');
    var returnTable = "<thead><tr><th>ItemId</th><th>Lbs</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    var itemid = split[0];
    if(/^\d+$/.test(itemid)) return; //itemId is not a valid number: return now.

    var lbs = $('#lbs').val();
    tempList[itemid] = lbs; //refer by value, removed quotes around `itemId`.
    for (var i in tempList){
        returnTable += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + tempList[i] + '</td></tr>';
    }
    returnTable += "</tbody>";


    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.innerHTML = returnTable;

    //Various methods to add the table to your document are shown below
    // For each example, I assume that that specific element exists

    //When the data should be APPENDED to an existing TABLE ("#existingTable")
    var tblTo = document.getElementById("existingTable").tBodies[0];
    for(var i=0, len=tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i<len; i++){
        tblTo.appendChild(tbl.tBodies[0].rows[0]);
        //Removes the row from the temporary table, appends row to tblTo
    }

    //When the new table should replace the previous table ("#prevTable"):
    var prevTbl = document.getElementById("prevTable");
    prevTbl.parentNode.replaceChild(tbl, prevTbl);

    //When the table should be APPENDED to a container ("#container")
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(tbl);

    //When the new table should replace the contents of a container ("#container")
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = "";
    container.appendChild(tbl);
});
```

Comment: I already have one in the "for loop" do I have to make another outside the loop?

Comment: I have indented your code, and saw: `for(var i; i<=(tempList.length  -1); i++){`. At this point, `i` is initialised at `undefined`. The condition `undefined<=(tempList.length-1)` always evaluates to false, and your code won't run.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried changing it into i=0 but it still does nothing. Is the part tempList.push(tempList['itemid'] = lbs correct, I kind of suspect that is the problem?

Comment: If you explain the expected result of your script, I will optimize the code for you.

Comment: When the "add" button is clicked, it stores the itemid (as index) and lbs (as value) then displays the object (itemid & lbs) inside the array in a alert box. So if add is clicked 3 times, there would 3 objects in the array displayed.

Comment: It's displaying something now, but only lbs and not itemid.

Comment: Shouldn't `itemid` be a number?  Shouldn't array indexes like `tempList[itemid]` be numbers?  And, is `lbs` intended to be a number too?

Comment: I force `itemId` to be a number (see the condition right after `split[0]`. Currently, `Lbs` can be anything, including numbers.

Comment: I got it working now, using for in loop and Rob W's code...thanks! BTW my itemid is alphanumeric.

Comment: If `itemId` is alphanumeric, you have to define `tempLIst` as `var tempList = {};`, and loop through it by `for(var i in tempList){/*i = itemId, tempList[i] = Lbs*/}`.

Comment: Hi, hope you dont mind another question but how do I display the content of tempList[] in a table?

Comment: Updated answer to answer your new question.